# asp.net controls with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I know this is probably a simple fix but I can't seem to figure out the issue here...

I am trying to disable withinthepast text box when RadioButton1 is clicked.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Checked="True" GroupName="DateTimeQuery" OnClick="javascript:TimeRangeClickEvent()"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="withinthepast" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:TextBox>

<script>
        function TimeRangeClickEvent()
        {
            var radio1 = document.getElementById('<%=RadioButton1.ClientID%>').checked;                

            if (radio1 == true)
            {
                var within = document.getElementById('<%=withinthepast.ClientID%>').enabled = false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Did you try adding a few console.log statements to monitor what is going on in TimeRangeClickEvent? You could add: console.log('radio1: ' + radio1); before the "if" to see if radio1 is really true. The console can be viewed with F12 in most browsers (AFAIK). And same question as Alex: why the "within" variable?

Comment: I just tested with an alert and it does in fact alert "true" if checked and "false" if not. <script>
        function TimeRangeClickEvent()
        {
            var radio1 = document.getElementById("<%=RadioButton1.ClientID %>").checked;
            if (radio1 == true) {
                alert(radio1);
            }
            else {
                alert(radio1);
            }
        }
    </script>

Comment: But if I try to disable the text box I still get the correct alerts and nothing happens to the text box being enabled/disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably with the "enabled" property. You can try this:

To enable a control: `ctl.removeAttribute("disabled")`

To disable a control: `ctl.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")`

Comment: Yep. Thank you that worked! Much appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (radio1.checked == true)
        {
            var within = document.getElementById('<%=withinthepast.ClientID%>').enabled = false;
        }
```

you can add attributes clientIdMode = static

Comment: Nope sorry.  Didn't have any effect.  I shouldn't have to put the OnClick event on the textbox as well right? Also, if i do cllientIDMode = static isn't there a chance I could end up with controls sharing the same ID as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057490/is-there-any-drawback-to-set-clientidmode-static-on-every-object-set-on-main

Comment: Any other suggestions anyone? I'm at a loss here. Nothing I have tried seems to be working...