# Jquery 2 clicks event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I had a page with many `FileUploads` and I am having a problem with jQuery to fire up 2 `.click` events to remove files at the certain point when a `RadioBoxList` `.click`(is selected) event, two buttons calling same function as `delete_Click` on code behind..

My code as following :

```html
<asp:Button ID="delBtn1" runat="server" Text="DeleteFile" OnClick="delete_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:Button ID="delBtn2" runat="server" Text="DeleteFile" OnClick="delete_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

```js
$("#rblist").click(function() {
  if ($("#rbl_1").prop("checked")) {
    $(".someclass").hide();
    uploadCheck1();
    uploadCheck2();
    $("delBtn1").click();
    $('delBtn2').click();
  }
});
```

first click never fired, wondering where is the problem? I am new to jQuery and hoping someone can point out my mistake,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need `ClientID` to get ASP.NET controls with jQuery:

```
$('#<%= rblist.ClientID %>').click(function() {
if ($('#<%= rbl_1.ClientID %>').prop("checked")) {
$(".someclass").hide();
uploadCheck1();
uploadCheck2();
$('#<%= delBtn1.ClientID %>').click();
$('#<%= delBtn2.ClientID %>').click();
}
});
```

Comment: with ClientIDMode="Static" attribute I can use static ID no?

Comment: @Jackson...Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057490/is-there-any-drawback-to-set-clientidmode-static-on-every-object-set-on-main

Comment: @Shree...Take a look at this post: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/May/04/Whats-New-in-ASPNET-40-Part-Two-WebForms-and-Visual-Studio-Enhancements

Answer (score 0):

### Use the dblclick event

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").dblclick(function(){
        alert("The the page.");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you are selecting the button control with id so you need to specify the Jquery id selector(#)

try below code

```
$("#rblist").click(function() {
  if ($("#rbl_1").prop("checked")) {
    $(".someclass").hide();
    uploadCheck1();
    uploadCheck2();
    $("#delBtn1").click(); //change here
    $('#delBtn2').click();//change here
  }
});
```

Comment: you have to use $("#<%= delBtn2.ClientID %>") to get the id rendered to the client!