# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'type' of null

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm using the master page in asp.net and receiving the following error in the chrome browser inspection tool console.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'type' of null
at myFunction (StudentPassword.aspx:258)
at HTMLInputElement.onclick**

*I guess that the problem is with the script tag. where should I place it? Inside  tag or at the bottom of content page or at the bottom of the master page?*

Masterpage is:

```
  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Student.master.cs" Inherits="Project_Placements.Student" %>

 <!DOCTYPE HTML>

 <HTML>
 <head runat="server">
 </head>
 <body>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   
       function myFunction() {
           var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
           var pwd = document.getElementById("password");
           if (checkBox.checked == true) {
               pwd.type = 'password';
           } else {
               pwd.type = 'text';
           }
       }
   }
   </script>    
   </body>
   </html>
```

and the content page code is as follows:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Student.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
 CodeBehind="StudentPassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project_Placements.WebForm7" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">    
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server"  TextMode="Password" ></asp:TextBox>
 <label for="myCheck">Show Password :</label> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
  </form>
  </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getElementById not finding control generated by ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595823/getelementbyid-not-finding-control-generated-by-asp-net)

Comment: `var pwd = document.querySelector("[id$=myCheck]")`. To omit the serversided generated parent id chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.Net chains up all `id` from serverside ran parent elements to the `id` of the current element, unless overwritten on the server. So the outputted `id` actually  looks something like `ContentPlaceHolder1$Content3$form1$password`.

You can use the ends-with selector to omit this.

```
var pwd = document.querySelector("[id$=password]").
```

*Yet be aware to still choose unique `id` which will also be unique using ends-with.*

Alternatively you could use a data-attribute and select on that:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server"  TextMode="Password" data-id="password" />
var pwd = document.querySelector("[data-id=password]");
```

Finally you could use something like:

```
var pwd = document.getElementById('<%=password.ClientID %>');
```

*Yet I never really liked it and it demands the script to be inline.*

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the error because the script is getting loaded before the DOM is being rendered completely. Try placing the content of your script inside document.ready and that should solve the problem.

Comment: The issue is that the `id` of elements with `runat="server"`get chained up with all the parents, unless prevented by overwriting. So the outputed `id` is something like `ContentPlaceHolder1$Content3$form1$password`.