# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null error but element is not null

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Why do i get the uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null error ? I looked solutions on stackoverflow but everyone says you should not set your javascript code before your page gets loaded. But in my code my javascript code is coming after my html code.

This is where i get my true choice from database and it works successfully , i can get data :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="width: 100%; min-height: 600px; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" CssClass="" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4" CellSpacing="17">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <span runat="server" id="mychoice"> <%# Eval("SynonymOppositeTrueChoice") %></span>
              
            <section class="btns-section">
                <img class="main-img" src="<%# Eval("SynonymOppositeQuestionImg") %>" id="mainimglink"></img>



            </section>


            <section style="width:600px;display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:space-around;">
              
                <img id="img1" onclick="selectA();"  class="synonym-choices" src="<%# Eval("SynonymOppositeImage1") %>" />
                <img id="img2" onclick="selectB();"  class="synonym-choices" src="<%# Eval("SynonymOppositeImage2") %>" />
                <img id="img3" onclick="selectC();"  class="synonym-choices" src="<%# Eval("SynonymOppositeImage3") %>" />
            </section>

                   <section id="btn-section" class="btns-section" style="visibility:hidden;">
                <asp:Button  ID="ButtonNext" OnClick="ButtonNext_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btn-next-testtwo"  Text="&#8594;" />
            </section>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</form>


<script>
    const trueselection = document.getElementById("mychoice");
    const btnNextSection = document.getElementById("btn-section");
    const imgone = document.getElementById("img1");
    const imgtwo = document.getElementById("img2");
    const imgthree = document.getElementById("img3");

    function selectA() {
       
        if (parseInt(trueselection.innerHTML) == 1) {
            btnNextSection.style.visibility = "visible";
            selectionOneImg.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        else {
            imgone.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }

    function selectB() {
        if (parseInt(trueselection.innerHTML) == 2) {
            btnNextSection.style.visibility = "visible";
            selectionOneImg.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        else {
            imgtwo.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }

    function selectC() {
        if (parseInt(trueselection.innerHTML) == 3) {
            btnNextSection.style.visibility = "visible";
            selectionOneImg.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        else {
            imgthree.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

    }

</script>
```

</asp:Content>

Then this code works when i click an image:

```
 const trueselection = document.getElementById("mychoice");
    const btnNextSection = document.getElementById("btn-section");
    const imgone = document.getElementById("img1");
    const imgtwo = document.getElementById("img2");
    const imgthree = document.getElementById("img3");

    function selectA() {
       
        if (parseInt(trueselection.innerHTML) == 1) {
            btnNextSection.style.visibility = "visible";
            selectionOneImg.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        else {
            imgone.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
```

And i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" error in my console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getElementById not finding control generated by ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595823/getelementbyid-not-finding-control-generated-by-asp-net)

Comment: Please provide the full HTML.

Comment: Place script after HTML

Comment: I am scripting after html already.

Comment: I edited question as full code.

Comment: You're not setting `.innerHTML` anywhere in the code you've posted; my guess is the error is referring to a script further up.

Comment: Thanks for all of your helps i solved it :) Asp was setting random new id for my element. So i could not get element by id. I setted  ClientIDMode="Static" so i can use the id which i setted.

Comment: Then answer your own question in case anyone else has the same problem.

Comment: Okay im answering now .

Comment: No need to answer. This has already been answered in the  post linked in my first comment. [Please don't spread the information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE The question was already marked as a dupe, correctly. Please don't tell people to answer dupes.

Answer (score 2):

I solved error finally :) Asp was setting random new id for my element. So i could not get element by id.

So if you get this error. Asp.net may change your element id values. To prevent asp.net's this behaviour, set:

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

To element which you want to prevent problem with changing id .

Comment: The question was already marked as duplicate. I'm sorry you got wrong advice; there's no need to post an answer if your question is a dupe. You should rather consider deleting the question in such a case.